# how to make bootstrap dropdown to fill the entire col width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

By default, dropdown on bootstrap are dynamic based on the length of the text of the selected item. This will break the harmony of my layout and I can't find a solution.

Basically I want a row containing a search input and on the right side a dropbox. Something very simple...How to make this possible ?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="searchAndLogin">
   <div class="col-md-9">
       <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the width of the `btn-group` and its `btn` elements as well as the `dropdown-menu` to fit the width of the column you place it on.

CSS

```
#searchAndLogin .btn-group {width:100%;}
#searchAndLogin .btn-group .btn {width:90%;}
#searchAndLogin .btn-group .btn.dropdown-toggle {width:10%;}
#searchAndLogin .btn-group .dropdown-menu {width:100%;}
```

Live example here: http://www.bootply.com/WPhb5tLZmh